# Large Deviations Question

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, large-deviation-theory

Let $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geq 1}$ be i.i.d random variables on $\left(\Omega,\mathcal A, \mathbb P\right)$, $X_1$ with mean $\mu$, and

$$
L(\lambda) =
\begin{cases}
\log\mathbb E\left(e^{\lambda X_1}\right)<\infty, & \text{if }\mathbb E\left(e^{\lambda X_1}\right)<\infty \\
+\infty, & \text{otherwise, }
\end{cases}
$$

If $$\displaystyle L^{*}(x)=\sup\left(x\lambda-L(\lambda)|\lambda\in\mathbb R\right)$$

Prove that for any $\alpha >0$ and $n \geq 1$,

$$\mathbb P\left(\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}-\mu\geq \alpha\right)\leq e^{-nL^{*}(\mu+\alpha)}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality take $\mu = 0$ and fix any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.  Call $S_n =\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.  Then
$$ P\left( \frac{1}{n}S_n \geq \alpha\right) = P\left(e^{\lambda S_n} \geq e^{n \lambda \alpha}\right)$$
$$ \leq e^{-n \lambda \alpha} E[e^{\lambda X_1}]^n$$
$$ = e^{-n(\lambda \alpha - L(\lambda))} $$

Now take the supremum over $\lambda$ to get the result.

Comment: Should the $X_1$ be in the exponent?

Comment: yeah that's a formatting error, I'll fix it.

Comment: Can you help me understand why $P(e^{\lambda S_n} \geq e^{n \lambda \alpha})\leq e^{-n \lambda \alpha} E[e^{\lambda X_1}]^n$?

Comment: Apply Markov's inequality.