# Law of Large Numbers Deduction

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

Let $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geq 1}$ be i.i.d random variables on $\left(\Omega,\mathcal A, \mathbb P\right)$, $X_1$ with mean $\mu$, and $$
L(\lambda) =
\begin{cases}
\log\mathbb E\left(e^{\lambda X_1}\right)<\infty, & \text{if }\mathbb E\left(e^{\lambda X_1}\right)<\infty \\
+\infty, & \text{otherwise, }
\end{cases}
$$

and $\displaystyle L^{*}(x)=\sup\left(x\lambda-L(\lambda)|\lambda\in\mathbb R\right)$

Prove that for any $\alpha > 0$ and $n\geq 1$,

$$\mathbb P\left(\left|\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}-\mu\right|\geq \alpha\right)\leq e^{-nL^{*}(\mu+\alpha)}+e^{-nL^{*}(\mu-\alpha)}$$

And deduce the most general law of large numbers you can from the previous inequality.

Comment: Hint: As a first step to deriving the general law of large numbers, you could for example calculate, $L$, $L^{*}$, for $\pm 1$ or Cauchy random variables and see what happens in the inequality.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349587/large-deviations-question is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mathbb P\left(\left|\frac{S_n}{n}-\mu\right|\geq\alpha\right)=\mathbb P\left(\frac{S_n}{n}-\mu\geq \alpha\right)+\mathbb P\left(-\frac{S_n}{n}+\mu\geq \alpha\right)$$

So we have to show that:

$$\mathbb P\left(\frac{S_n}{n}-\mu\geq \alpha\right)+\mathbb P\left(-\frac{S_n}{n}+\mu\geq \alpha\right)\leq e^{-nL^{*}(\mu+\alpha)}+e^{-nL^{*}(\mu-\alpha)}$$

$$\mathbb P\left(\frac{S_n}{n}-\mu\geq\alpha\right)\leq e^{-nL^{*}(\mu+\alpha)}$$

Similarly we have

$$\mathbb P\left(-\frac{S_n}{n}+\mu\geq \alpha\right)\leq e^{-nL^{*}(\mu-\alpha)}$$